# How do i use getText() on an editText field while the editText is inside another onclick?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, gettext

Currently the issue with my application is that when switching views of my application via a floating action buttons onClickListener, i cannot access what is being put inside my editText because it is being created in a separate for loop.

---

```
start_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
for(int j=0;j<amount;j++){

                ...
                final  EditText team = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                team.setHint("TeamName");
                team.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                ll.addView(team);

                ...
                });

                lm.addView(ll);
            }
            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {


        if(lm.getVisibility()==View.GONE|lm2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                            lm2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            lm2.removeAllViews();
                            lm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else{
         if(lm.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE|lm2.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                       lm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       for(int x=0;x<amount;x++){
                               if(myStringArray[x]==null){
                                   myStringArray[x]="Empty Team Name";
                                   x--;
                               }else {
                                   myStringArray[x] = (team.getText().toString());
                                   TextView score_name = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                   TextView final_score = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                   score_name.setTextSize(15);
                                   score_name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                   final_score.setTextSize(25);
                                   score_name.setLayoutParams(params);
                                   final_score.setLayoutParams(params);
                                   lm2.addView(score_name);
                                   lm2.addView(final_score);
                                   String a = Arrays.toString(myIntArray);
                                   String ar[] = a.substring(1, a.length() - 1).split(", ");

                                   score_name.append(myStringArray[x]);
                                   final_score.append(ar[x]);
                                   score_name.append("\n");
                               }
                            }
                            lm2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

currently it is not recognizing the variable (team) when using

myStringArray[x] = (team.getText().toString());

I have tried moving around my initializer, {{final  EditText team = new EditText(MainActivity.this);}}, but if i move it outside the for loop the application crashes upon the onclick of start_button

Comment: Is `EditText` is the only view type you are adding to `ll` and is `ll` the only(single) viewgroup in `lm`

Answer (score 0):

Define your EditText team out site of `start_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()` then initialise it in `onClickListener` method. Check the code below.

```
final  EditText team;
start_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
for(int j=0;j<amount;j++){

                team = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                team.setHint("TeamName");
                team.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                ll.addView(team);

                ...
                });

                lm.addView(ll);
            }
            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {


        if(lm.getVisibility()==View.GONE|lm2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                            lm2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            lm2.removeAllViews();
                            lm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else{
         if(lm.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE|lm2.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                       lm.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       for(int x=0;x<amount;x++){
                               if(myStringArray[x]==null){
                                   myStringArray[x]="Empty Team Name";
                                   x--;
                               }else {
                                   myStringArray[x] = (team.getText().toString());
                                   TextView score_name = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                   TextView final_score = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                   score_name.setTextSize(15);
                                   score_name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                   final_score.setTextSize(25);
                                   score_name.setLayoutParams(params);
                                   final_score.setLayoutParams(params);
                                   lm2.addView(score_name);
                                   lm2.addView(final_score);
                                   String a = Arrays.toString(myIntArray);
                                   String ar[] = a.substring(1, a.length() - 1).split(", ");

                                   score_name.append(myStringArray[x]);
                                   final_score.append(ar[x]);
                                   score_name.append("\n");
                               }
                            }
                            lm2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: when i tried initializing the variable this way, it tells me i cannot assign a value to the final variable team, and it needs to be final to be accessed from the inner class. Android studio suggested i make the team variable a one element array but that only returns the final word entered into the editText box.

Comment: @BlakeDukes you can define the fields as class variables and then they qon't be kept final

Comment: i got it to work with team set as an array of editText with size dependent on loop variable sizes.